# Need (IF(AND)) Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

All.

I am trying to create a formula when there are multiple conditions (three - specifically).

For Example:

1. If Cell A1=ABC then the value in Cell B1 must be less than 100, if is less 100 then it should show "pass", else it should show "fail".
2. If Cell A1=DEF then the value in Cell B1 must be less than 150, if is less than 150 then it should show "pass", else it should show "fail".
3. If Cell A1=GHI then the value in Cell B1 must be less than 200, if is less than 200 then it should show "pass", else it should show "fail".

I am trying IF(OR for the above to put them into one single formula, but cant get it to work!
Can someone help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in `Column C`,

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="ABC",B1<100),AND(A1="DEF",B1<150),AND(A1="GHI",B1<200)),"Pass","Fail")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gowtham - It worked. I changed the < to > because when the value was 100/150/200 it was showing as Fail which is not a Fail actually since all of them are okay to be at those values.

Thank you again!

Comment: you can change it to `<=` , i guess that would work. Please mark answer as correct to make the question resolved

Comment: @Charlie If the test should be `<=` you should also update the question to say so - at the moment it says it is a pass if it is less than 100 etc.

Comment: @YowE3K - Yeah, my bad, i should have mentioned that.. Fairly new here :)

Comment: @Gowtham - Yeah, i will do it now. Thank you!